# Optimize Python Double for Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, double

Below is my python code

```
myList = ['A','B','C','D','E',...]   #all elements is string
myDict = [D1,D2]  # let consider 2 dict
# D1 = {'A':0.1,'B':0.5,'C':0.01,...}    
# D2 = {'A':0.4,'B':0.11,'C':0.21,...}

myNewDict = {}
for words in myList:
    NewList = []
    for dicts in myDict:
           tmps = dicts[words]
           NewList.append(tmps)
    myNewDict[words] = (min(NewList), max(NewList))
```

I using Python 3.4 with 64-bit, so i would like have some suggestions on how to improve the performance of the code by using python built-in function or any better way to improve calculation time. Here sincere thank above your suggestion and idea. Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to give you suggestions if you could post a complete working example with actual values filled in for `myList` and `myDict`. They don't have to have 100 and 60 entries each in the original example, just a few will do. That way we can see what the actual data looks like.

Comment: … although knowing the actual _sizes_ would be great, because a lot of optimizations that make sense for, say, a small list of huge dictionaries that you use once won't make sense for, say, a small list of small dictionaries that you use a zillion times.

Comment: Dear Michaael and Abarnet , thanks. I improve the example already, thanks.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic because it's about improving performance in general. You might have better luck on [CodeReview.SE], once the above issues are addressed and the copy is edited a bit more, so I'm flagging for migration.

Comment: This still doesn't answer Michael Geary's point. It isn't an actual working example that we can run, profile, and optimize for you.

Comment: Also, when you're asking for optimization help, it's usually a good idea to explain what the problem is. Are you doing this a billion times and need to squeeze 10% off the total time? Are you doing it once, and expected it to take 300ms but instead it took 10 minutes? Do you think there's an algorithmic problem (e.g., you think it could be linear, but you don't know how to make it better than quadratic)?

Comment: Dear abarnet, sorry i new to python, so profile is it mean "python profilers" ?

Comment: One quick suggestion, if you're looking for a few percentage points: a list comprehension is usually about 20% faster than an explicit `for` statement around `list.append`: `NewList = [dicts[word] for dicts in myDict]`. But really, you don't need the list at all; all you're doing is calculating the minimum and maximum. So, don't build it.

Comment: I meant "profile" in a looser sense. Maybe using the `profile` or `cProfile` module or similar third-party modules, but maybe just manually taking pieces of your code and benchmarking them with `timeit`. And then, once we know (either way) which part is slow, benchmarking different alternative implementations with `timeit`.

Comment: Dear abarnert, thank for your suggestion, will recheck my code with cProfile, thank to all expert advice and suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looked like a neat exercise where I could finally use `tee`, so I made this:

```
from itertools import tee
words = ['A','B','C']
dicts = [{'A': 0.1, 'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.01},
         {'A': 0.4, 'B': 0.11, 'C': 0.21}]
newdict = {word: (min(minfeed), max(maxfeed))
           for word in words
           for minfeed, maxfeed in [tee(d[word] for d in dicts)]}
```

Output:

```
{'B': (0.11, 0.5), 'C': (0.01, 0.21), 'A': (0.1, 0.4)}
```

Edit: I was curious and tried some more versions and did speed tests with large random data, 100000 words and 100 dictionaries. Results first:

```
 5.418 seconds Chin
 4.364 seconds Stefan
 3.460 seconds Stefan2
 3.471 seconds Stefan3
```

The code:

```
from itertools import tee
def Stefan(words, dicts):
    return {word: (min(minfeed), max(maxfeed))
            for word in words
            for minfeed, maxfeed in [tee(d[word] for d in dicts)]}

def Stefan2(words, dicts):
    out = {}
    for word in words:
        values = [d[word] for d in dicts]
        out[word] = min(values), max(values)
    return out

def Stefan3(words, dicts):
    return {word: (min(values), max(values))
            for word in words
            for values in [[d[word] for d in dicts]]}

def Chin(myList, myDict):
    myNewDict = {}
    for words in myList:
        NewList = []
        for dicts in myDict:
               tmps = dicts[words]
               NewList.append(tmps)
        myNewDict[words] = (min(NewList), max(NewList))
    return myNewDict

from random import sample, randrange, random
from string import ascii_letters
from time import time

WORDS = 100000
DICTS = 100

def random_word():
    ''.join(sample(ascii_letters, randrange(2, 10)))
words = [random_word() for _ in range(WORDS)]
dicts = [{w: random() for w in words} for _ in range(DICTS)]

prev = None
for func in Chin, Stefan, Stefan2, Stefan3:
    t0 = time()
    result = func(words, dicts)
    print('%6.3f seconds' % (time() - t0), func.__name__)
    if prev and result != prev:
        print('fail')
    prev = result
```

Comment: Hi, Stefan Pochmann, thanks for your suggestion and advice, definitely  will try out the suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @ChinLim I was curious myself did some more, see updated answer. It's a bit faster than yours for the data I tried, but it depends on the data. If we knew more about your data, there might be better solutions (possibly even with really different approaches, not just "syntax variations").